# function parameter in addEventListener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Basic question. When I create an eventlistener as below and give the function the parameter **e**, what is **e**? If I understand it right its just the name of the event object?

```
document.getElementById('theId').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Then what about this example? Does the event create an object in this case without a name?

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener('submit', function(){
    alert("Hello World!");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Parameter **e** would be the event that happend, and yes **e** is just a name. You can give it any name you whant.

Events have their own properties, and one of them is "type" so you can know what event happened. In this example its type is "click" since that is what we are listening for.

Take look at this example

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(myEvent){
    console.log(myEvent);
});
```

```html
<p>Click anywhere.</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

When the event 'submit' is fired, the given function gets called with an event object as the first argument.

You can name it as you like

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener('submit', function(someEvent){
    someEvent.preventDefault();
});
```

If you dont give the parameter a name, you still can access it over the arguments object.

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener('submit', function(){
    arguments[0].preventDefault();
});
```

It behaves like an array, but does not support functions like arguments.pop

More information on the arguments object [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)